# Can't access Collection Group resource data in Cloud Firestore rules

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I have a collection /calendars with a subcollection /events. I'm trying to set up rules for querying /events as a Collection Group, but can't seem to access the resource.data fields. All documents in /calendars/events have a field "CalendarId" and for testing purposes I've setup the rules as can be seen below:

```js
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{path=**}/events/{eventId} {
      allow read: if 'CalendarId' in resource.data;
    }
  }
}
```

I then try to query the /events collection through a Collection Group query:

```js
firestore.collectionGroup('events').where('UserId', '==', userId).get()
```

But the above query yields me the following error:

```js
FirebaseError: Missing or insufficient permissions
```

However, if I change the "allow read" rules to the following, the query works and returns the correct documents as expected:

```js
allow read: if !('CalendarId' in resource.data);
```

Why is it that the 'CalendarId' field is unavailable in the rules even though it is present in all of the /events documents?

For comparison, querying individual /calendars or /events document works great with use of the following rules:

```js
match /calendars/{calendarId} {

  allow write: if resource == null || isOwner();
  allow read: if resource.data.IsPublic || isOwner();
  
  match /events/{eventId} {
  
    function calendarOwner() {
        return get(/databases/$(database)/documents/calendars/$(calendarId)).data.UserId
    }
  
    allow write: if request.auth != null && request.auth.uid == calendarOwner();
    allow read: if resource.data.IsPublic || (request.auth != null && request.auth.uid == calendarOwner());
  }
  
}
```

Comment: Maybe you could edit the question to include the code and rules that do work so we can see the difference?  I would not expect the rule and code to work at all for a regular collection query that doesn't have any filters.  Your rule requires a filter in the query.

Comment: @DougStevenson I've added the filters that I use when querying the Collection Group. I've also added rules that I use for querying individual /events documents.

Comment: Two things: 1) That doesn't look like working code.  You can't chain where() after get(). 2) Your rules look like they require a filter on a CalendarID field, and I'm not even sure if the syntax you're using is valid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Security [rules are not filters](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-conditions#rules_are_not_filters), but instead merely detect whether the access is permitted. Since your rule says:

```
if 'CalendarId' in resource.data;
```

And your code then does:

```
firestore.collectionGroup('events').get().where('UserId', '==', userId)
```

The code violates the rules, since it is requesting potential documents that don't have a `CalendarId` field.

You will have to make sure the query has at least the same conditions as your rules check for, for example by checking whether the calendar (if it's a string) is `>=` to `""`.

Comment: Everyone expects resource.data to be truly resource.data, but it's not.  It's resource.{query}data

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what that means @jprio. But if you think that there is a better way to answer this question, I recommend posting an alternative answer below.